# Node.js require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I work on a node.js web application and I use javascript server side. I have an error that blocks me every time i use "require" :

```
var documentClient = require ("documentdb"). DocumentClient;
```

the error is: `require is not defined.`

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: `var documentClient = require("documentdb").DocumentClient;`

Comment: what do you have above it?

Comment: I have "require 2.4.20" instaled using npm. I work using angular framework.

Comment: I am confused. Are you trying to use `require` on the server side of the code or the browser side of code in Angular framework?